# Laravel 4: authentication not working when public folder is a subdomain

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

**I'm making this edit to clarify things**, read the stuff below the edit if you need more info please.

Basically I have deployed my laravel cms into a subdirectory on a site so that the usual laravel 'public' folder is now example.com/blog

The app works fine when I deploy it to the root i.e. example.com but not when I deploy it to a subdirectory/subfolder (see my paths etc below). The blog articles are showing up fine on the main /blog index page and so it doesn't appear to be an issue with paths (though I could be wrong)

**The problem:** I am having trouble logging in to the back end of my cms because authentication is failing.

I just tested this by making a change to my login controller:

```
public function user()
{
            $username = Input::get('username');
            $password = Input::get('password');

    if(Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password)))
    {
        // we are now logged in go here
        return Redirect::to('test');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('wrongdetails');
    }
}
```

and my route:

```
Route::get('test', function()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        return 'the user is logged in';
    }else
    {
        return 'the user is not logged in';
    }
});

Route::get('wrongdetails', function()
{
    return 'wrong password';
});
```

**The results**: if I submit the correct details to my login form it directs me to /test and tells me the user is **not** logged in and if I submit wrong details it takes me to the wrong details page. Any ideas?

---

---

I've built a custom cms - logging into the back end works perfectly when the 'public' folder is at the root of my domain i.e. public_html for a shared host.

But for a recent project I've had to use a subfolder '/blog' as my root 'public' folder and now it's not authenticating properly.

let me digress - the application works like this:

You log in at www.example.com/blog/secure/login which directs to the back end at example.com/blog/cms

The example.com/blog/cms is only accessible if you are authenticated. If not authenticated it redirects to the login page via a filter.php

The relevant part of my route.php looks like this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('cms', 'PostsController');
});

Route::get('secure/login', function()
{
    return View::make('secure/loginForm');
});

Route::post('secure/login', 'UserLogin@user');
```

and my loginForm view relevantly looks like this:

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' => '/secure/login', 'class' => 'box login')); ?>
<fieldset class="boxBody">
 <label>Username</label>
 <input type="text" tabindex="1" name="username" required>
 <label>Password</label>
 <input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" required>
 <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Login" tabindex="4">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And finally my controller looks like this:

```
public function user()
{
    // get POST data
    $userdata = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($userdata))
    {
        // we are now logged in, go to admin
        return Redirect::to('/cms');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('secure/login');
    }
}
```

It works, in the sense that it passes the if statement in the controller to go to /cms but when it gets to /cms it is redirected to the login page because it does not view me as authenticated.

Can anyone see any reason why the authentication would not be carrying over? As I said, it works if the public folder is the root of the domain but not in a subfolder.

This may help - the relevant part of filters.php looks like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) 
    return Redirect::to('secure/login');
});
```

I know it is passing the 'if' statement in the controller because if I change my filter to Redirect::to('http://google.com'); it redirects to Google. Meaning that the login works and then passes to the /cms but the /cms directory picks me up as non authenticated and send me to Google.com, if that makes sense.

My paths have been changed to get the cms to point to a subdomain, here is the relevant parts of my bootstrap/paths.php:

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../../mycms/app',
'public' => __DIR__,
'base' => __DIR__.'/../../mycms',
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../../mycms/app/storage',
```

And also my index.php in my /blog subdirectory:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../mycms/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../mycms/bootstrap/start.php';
```

This is absolutely doing my head in, ha.

Comment: Your sure it takes you to cms, then redirects you back there and its not actually failing to login?

Comment: Yes, I tried the controller if statement with a line getting it to print the authentication and the answer to that print was '1' meaning it successfully worked. If I change my filters.php to redirect to google.com instead of back to the login it redirects to Google, meaning login works and sends me to the /cms page but then gets redirected to google.com via the filter

Comment: It does work when your in the public folder though? Have you tried setting your application URL in the config?

Comment: config/app.php is set to 'url' => 'http://mydomain.com/blog', and still if I set my filters.php to if (Auth::guest()) 
    return Redirect::to('http://google.com'); it takes me to google

Comment: also, see my edit just then, showing how my paths.php points to my /blog subdirectory. As I said, it works fine when my public is the root of my domain.

Comment: Are you redirected to the subdomain when you go to the subdomain directory in your browser? Are you ultimately going to attempt to go to the URL via the subdomain or the subfolder paths?

Comment: @fideloper I'm using a subdirectory/subfolder so the laravel 'public' folder is now /home/username/example.com/blog for me where example.com is the root public_html. Everything else is stored above the root at /home/username/mycms from what I can see, my authentication is not being remembered so that when I go to example.com/blog/cms it filters me out as not authenticated, even though I just logged in on the previous page.

Comment: Looking at your route, it seems like the authentication form uses HTTPS. I'm assuming the rest of the site don't. If that's the case, you may have to disable secure only cookies on your config.

Comment: Hi @ViníciusFragosoPinheiro where is that setting changed? :)

Comment: @Josh, it seems that `laravel` is not counting you as an authenticated user so, because of `filter` you are being redirected to a `login form`. So, it's clear tat the problem is in `authentication`, to debug it, you may disable the `auth` filter temporarily and see if it let you be in that page.

Comment: Try add `RewriteBase /blog` to your `.htaccess` file.